# OpenCV Error: Bad argument (The total number of matrix elements is not divisible by the new number of rows) in reshape

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, opencv

Ситуация такая: Насколько я понял функция ниже возвращает cv::Mat по HWND окна, если брать HWND desktop или не менять размер исследуемого окна, то все нормально, но если поменять размер окна, узнать его HWND, а потом запустить эту функцию то приложение вылетает с ошибкой:

```
OpenCV Error: Bad argument (The total number of matrix elements is not divisible by the new number of rows) in reshape, file G:\qt\opencv\opencv\sources\modules\core\src\matrix.cpp, line 1056
```

Функция:

```
cv::Mat hwnd3mat(HWND hwnd)
{
    HDC hwindowDC,hwindowCompatibleDC;

    int height,width,srcheight,srcwidth;
    HBITMAP hbwindow;
    cv::Mat src;
    BITMAPINFOHEADER  bi;

    hwindowDC=GetDC(hwnd);
    hwindowCompatibleDC=CreateCompatibleDC(hwindowDC);
    SetStretchBltMode(hwindowCompatibleDC,COLORONCOLOR);

    RECT windowsize;    // get the height and width of the screen
    GetClientRect(hwnd, &windowsize);

    srcheight = windowsize.bottom;
    srcwidth = windowsize.right;
    height = windowsize.bottom/1;  //change this to whatever size you want to resize to
    width = windowsize.right/1;
    qDebug() <<"height="<<height;
    qDebug() <<"width="<<width;
    src.create(height,width,CV_8UC4);

    // create a bitmap
    hbwindow = CreateCompatibleBitmap( hwindowDC, width, height);
    bi.biSize = sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER);    //http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/window/dd183402%28v=vs.85%29.aspx
    bi.biWidth = width;
    bi.biHeight = -height;  //this is the line that makes it draw upside down or not
    bi.biPlanes = 1;
    bi.biBitCount = 32;
    bi.biCompression = BI_RGB;
    bi.biSizeImage = 0;
    bi.biXPelsPerMeter = 0;
    bi.biYPelsPerMeter = 0;
    bi.biClrUsed = 0;
    bi.biClrImportant = 0;

    // use the previously created device context with the bitmap

    SelectObject(hwindowCompatibleDC, hbwindow);
    // copy from the window device context to the bitmap device context
    StretchBlt( hwindowCompatibleDC, 0,0, width, height, hwindowDC, 0, 0,srcwidth,srcheight, SRCCOPY); //change SRCCOPY to NOTSRCCOPY for wacky colors !
    GetDIBits(hwindowCompatibleDC,hbwindow,0,height,src.data,(BITMAPINFO *)&bi,DIB_RGB_COLORS);  //copy from hwindowCompatibleDC to hbwindow

    // avoid memory leak
    DeleteObject (hbwindow);
    DeleteDC(hwindowCompatibleDC);
    ReleaseDC(hwnd, hwindowDC);

    return src;
}
```

Comment: В принципе я понимаю что это из-за src.create(height,width,CV_8UC(4)), В переводе ошибка значит: Общее число матричных элементов не делится на новое число строк, я делал так src.create(height,width,CV_8UC(3)) и 5, но так не работает получение пикселей цвета.

Comment: В какой строке этого кода происходит процитированная ошибка?

Comment: Ошибка происходит не тут, ошибка происходит при присваивании cv::Mat3b src0=src т.е. результата  функции hwnd3mat

Comment: К чему это здесь тогда? И почему отсутствует код, порождающий ошибку?

Comment: Потому что тогда я не знал, где вылет, забросил, а позже отдебажил написал новый вопрос где указано где ошибка.

Comment: Новый вопрос? Зачем был создан новый вопрос вместо добавления информации в уже существующий?