# Ошибка при конвертировании cv::Mat в cv::Mat3b

Tags: c++, opencv

Я работаю с библиотекой OpenCv + qt. Задача сравнивать цвета пикселей матрицы с определенными цветами и выводить результат. Чтобы получить цвет использую вот:

```
cv::Mat3b src=src0;
    for(int r = 0; r < src.rows; ++r) {
        for(int c = 0; c < src.cols; ++c) {
          cv::Vec3b pixel = src(r,c);
            uchar blue = pixel[0];
            uchar green = pixel[1];
            uchar red = pixel[2];
            qDebug() <<"blue="<<blue <<"green=" <<green <<"red=" <<red;
           // image(r,c);
        }
    }
```

Mat3b получаю из Mat. Но при использовании нестандартных размеров получаю вылет с ошибкой. Можно ли это как то исправить?

```
cv::Mat src;
src.create(488,665,CV_8UC(4));  
cv::Mat3b src0=src; //тут получаю вылет, пишет в консоли:
/*OpenCV Error: Bad argument (The total number of matrix elements is not divisible by the new number of rows) in reshape, file G:\qt\opencv\opencv\sources\modules\core\src\matrix.cpp, line 1056
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception'
  what():  G:\qt\opencv\opencv\sources\modules\core\src\matrix.cpp:1056: error: (-5) The total number of matrix elements is not divisible by the new number of rows in function reshape*/
```

В переводе ошибка значит: Общее число матричных элементов не делится на новое число строк, я делал так `src.create(height,width,CV_8UC(3))` и 5, но так не работает получение пикселей цвета. Библиотеку только начал изучать, так что 80% как там чего не знаю. 
В другом похожем вопросе не указано, где конкретно возникала, проблема. Тут же указано где возникает проблема, я просто не знаю как ее решить и прошу помощи.

Мне писали чтобы я выложил полностью код вылаживаю, main2 - запуск этого чуда где падает и когда написал выше:

```
QString titleWin = "boldt - Быстрый просмотр ACDSee";
cv::Mat hwnd3mat(HWND hwnd)
{
    HDC hwindowDC,hwindowCompatibleDC;

    int height,width,srcheight,srcwidth;
    HBITMAP hbwindow;
    cv::Mat src;
    BITMAPINFOHEADER  bi;

    hwindowDC=GetDC(hwnd);
    hwindowCompatibleDC=CreateCompatibleDC(hwindowDC);
    SetStretchBltMode(hwindowCompatibleDC,COLORONCOLOR);

    RECT windowsize;    // get the height and width of the screen
    GetClientRect(hwnd, &windowsize);

    srcheight = windowsize.bottom;
    srcwidth = windowsize.right;
    height = windowsize.bottom/1;  //change this to whatever size you want to resize to
    width = windowsize.right/1;
    qDebug() <<"height="<<height;
    qDebug() <<"width="<<width;

    src.create(height,width,CV_8UC(4));

    // create a bitmap
    hbwindow = CreateCompatibleBitmap( hwindowDC, width, height);
    bi.biSize = sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER);    //http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/window/dd183402%28v=vs.85%29.aspx
    bi.biWidth = width;
    bi.biHeight = -height;  //this is the line that makes it draw upside down or not
    bi.biPlanes = 1;
    bi.biBitCount = 32;
    bi.biCompression = BI_RGB;
    bi.biSizeImage = 0;
    bi.biXPelsPerMeter = 0;
    bi.biYPelsPerMeter = 0;
    bi.biClrUsed = 0;
    bi.biClrImportant = 0;

    // use the previously created device context with the bitmap

    SelectObject(hwindowCompatibleDC, hbwindow);
    // copy from the window device context to the bitmap device context
    StretchBlt( hwindowCompatibleDC, 0,0, width, height, hwindowDC, 0, 0,srcwidth,srcheight, SRCCOPY); //change SRCCOPY to NOTSRCCOPY for wacky colors !
    GetDIBits(hwindowCompatibleDC,hbwindow,0,height,src.data,(BITMAPINFO *)&bi,DIB_RGB_COLORS);  //copy from hwindowCompatibleDC to hbwindow

    // avoid memory leak
    DeleteObject (hbwindow);
    DeleteDC(hwindowCompatibleDC);
    ReleaseDC(hwnd, hwindowDC);

    return src;
}

void salt(cv::Mat image, int n) {
    HWND hwndDesktop = getHWND(titleWin);//GetDesktopWindow();
    LPTSTR lpString2=(LPTSTR)malloc (sizeof(TCHAR)*1000);
    int len2 = GetWindowText(hwndDesktop, lpString2, 1000);
    QString str2=QString::fromWCharArray(lpString2);
     cv::Mat src0 = hwnd3mat(hwndDesktop);
     cv::Mat3b src=src0;
    for(int r = 0; r < src.rows; ++r) {
        for(int c = 0; c < src.cols; ++c) { 
          cv::Vec3b pixel = src(r,c);
            uchar blue = pixel[0];
            uchar green = pixel[1];
            uchar red = pixel[2];
            qDebug() <<"blue="<<blue <<"green=" <<green <<"red=" <<red;
           // image(r,c);
        }
    }
    cv::imshow("output", src0);
}

int main2()
{
    // open the image
    cv::Mat3b image= cv::imread("searchimg.jpg",1);
    salt(image,3000);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: При чем здесь 4 и 5, если вы хотите получить 3-канальную марицу? "но так не работает получение пикселей цвета" не является осмысленным описанием проблемы. Что такое "не работает"?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [OpenCV Error: Bad argument (The total number of matrix elements is not divisible by the new number of rows) in reshape](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/697850/opencv-error-bad-argument-the-total-number-of-matrix-elements-is-not-divisible)

Comment: Не работает означает что в цикле вывода пикселей цвета  uchar blue = pixel[0]; итд 0 ли  или другое неверное значение цвета.

Comment: Ну, неверное, значит неверное... К чему вы здесь привели бессмысленный код, который в принципе неработоспособен (вылетает с исключением), вместо того, чтобы привести более-менее осмысленный код (пусть и с "неверным значением цвета") и спрашивать уже про него?

Comment: Я привел код, но он в принципе работоспособный, просто вылетает при  определенных width & height. Почему, и можно ли что то сделать и хочу узнать.